# Find dates common to all sites in data frame

Tags: r

I am working on a large data set and I want to find the dates common to all sites.

```
site <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4)
date <- c("4th Nov","5th Nov","6th Nov","5th Nov","6th Nov","7th Nov","8th Nov","5th Nov","6th Nov","6th Nov","7th Nov","8th Nov")
temperature <- c(3,5,7,3,6,8,5,3,5,7,8,9)
data <- data.frame(site,date,temperature)

common.dates(data)
[1] "6th Nov"
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please define "common to all sites".

Comment: There are no dates common to all sites in this data!

Comment: Thanks for noticing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that (even if it is not optimized) :

```
dates <- union(NULL,data$date)
sites <- union(data$site,NULL)

w <- array(0,length(dates)) # number sites per date
for (i in sites)
    for (j in 1:length(dates))
        w[j] <- w[j] + dates[j] %in% data$date[data$site==i]

dates[w == length(sites)] # returns the dates common to all sites
```

Comment: This one works better actually!

Comment: You mean that it is faster ?

Comment: I mean that `Reduce(intersect, split(data$date, data$site))` will not work on my "real" data frame and I am not sure why... but your method will. Since this is a work-related question, I'm not sure if it's worth it for me to troubleshoot it right away. Maybe later, but I just wanted to say this method is more flexible than the other.

Answer (score 6):

It works with a combination of `split`, `intersect`, and `Reduce`:

```
Reduce(intersect, split(data$date, data$site))

[1] "6th Nov"
```

Comment: @Arun Finally you got your `Reduce` example...

Comment: yes, although it would have made me happier if I were the one to think of this slick solution! :)

Answer (score 2):

One way using `plyr`:

```
with(ddply(data, .(date), function(x) all(1:4 %in% x$site)), date[V1 == TRUE])
# [1] 6th Nov
```